# How can i instance a java class like A: extends B implements C in kotlin

Tags: java, generics, kotlin

I have java classes like this below:

```
public class SomeClass<T extends ClassA & InterfaceA> {

    public SomeClass(T a, T b) {}

}

class A extends ClassA implements InterfaceA{}
class B extends ClassA implements InterfaceA{}
```

I'm trying to create an instance of SomeClass in kotlin at below, but I get a compile error:

**"infered type Any! is not a subtype of ClassA"**

but I'd know how to fix it. `A` and `B` at below extends `ClassA` and implements `InterfaceA`.

```
val someClass = SomeClass(A(), B())
```

Could someone help this out?

Comment: How does your Kotlin code look like? Which error do you get?

Comment: val someClass = SomeClass(a, b) the error is "infered type Any! is not a subtype of ClassA", but idk how to fix it. a and b extends ClassA and implements InterfaceA

Comment: You should update your question.

Comment: Kotlin needs you to specify type parameter, e. g. `SomeClass<SomeAnotherClass>()`

Comment: ok. i updated my answer

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include a [mcve]. I can not reproduce your error.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a [where-clause](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#upper-bounds) to define multiple upper bounds:

```
class SomeClass<T>(a: T, b: T)
    where T : ClassA, T : InterfaceA
```

---

Update, since apparently that wasn't the question. Let's say you have the code above (or the original Java), and a `ClassB` that inherits/implements the two types that are required from `T`, `ClassA` and `InterfaceA`.

```
open class ClassA
interface InterfaceA

class ClassB : ClassA(), InterfaceA
```

Creating an instance of `SomeClass` if you have an `a` and `b` that's of type `T` from somewhere (for example, they're instances of `ClassB`) then looks like this:

```
val a = ClassB()
val b = ClassB()
val someClass = SomeClass(a, b)
```

The long form of the last line with the type parameter included actually looks like this (but the type parameter can be inferred most of the time like you've seen above):

```
val someClass = SomeClass<ClassB>(a, b)
```

---

Edit again:

If you need to pass in instances of unrelated classes that match the type requirements, you'll need to give your `SomeClass` two type parameters:

```
public class SomeClass<T1 extends ClassA & InterfaceA, T2 extends ClassA & InterfaceA> {

    public SomeClass(T1 a, T2 b) {}

}
```

Comment: thats a Class definition, I want to know how I can get a instance of it.

Comment: thank you for your nice answer. the SomeClass takes two instances in the constructor, and both are different classes. sorry to mention it late. i updated my question

Comment: a and b should be instanciated from different classes, like val a = ClassB(), val b = ClassC() and both ClassB and ClassC extends ClassA and implements InterfaceA.

Comment: If one of those is a subclass of the other, then this will still work. If it's not, then you'll have to change the code of `SomeClass`, and give it two type parameters instead of just the one. Added code for this case too.

Answer (score 0):

Generic with multiple upper-bounds in Kotlin is painful. maybe it is a bug, there is no problem in java since both `A` and `B` are the subclasses of `ClassA` and `InterfaceA`.
but it can achieve your way by write an ugly method for the multi upper-bounds generic parameters. for example:

```
val error = SomeClass(A(), B());
val ok = new(A(), B());

//star projection means: <? extends ClassA & InterfaceA>
//                                             |
fun <F, S> new(first: F, second: S): SomeClass<*>
        where F : ClassA, F : InterfaceA,
              S : ClassA, S : InterfaceA {

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    return SomeClass(first,second as F);
    //           it is always ok  ---^
}
```

there is no problem in the code above, since the raw type of both `F` and `S` are `ClassA` and `InterfaceA` so it works fine in *runtime*, and [type inference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html) & [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.6) occurs in *compile-time* only.